# svcutil NOT generating specified fields for minOccurs=0

Tags: c#, wcf, svcutil.exe

I am generating a client proxy from a webservice using svcutil.
The WSDL contains elements that have the attribute minOccurs set to 0

```
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="dateMaxValue" type="xsd:dateTime"></xsd:element>
```

However the generated DataContract completly ignores this attribute and just create a normal dateMaxValue attribute without any dateMaxValueSpecified attribute

```
private System.DateTime dateMaxValueField;
```

When I generate the proxy using option /serializer:XmlSerializer, I get the xxxSpecified properties.

```
private System.DateTime dateMaxValueField;

private bool dateMaxValueFieldSpecified;
```

**EDIT**

For optional field, I want the field not being sent or not being read when they have no values (equivalent of specified=false with XmlSerializer)
Currently incoming and outcoming data are set to default values.
How can I obtain a similar behaviour with the DataContractSerializer ?
Or if it is already there, how can I use it ?

Comment: XmlSerializer and DataContractSerializer follow different serialization rules... does DCS even *observe* the `ShouldSerialize*` convention? But ultimately: if it isn't in this list, you probably can't make it do it automatically: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733(v=vs.110).aspx - you could perhaps do it manually in a `partial class`.

Comment: Well currently I have 140k lines of generated code and I may need momre. I am not editing every single class of that file to add required behaviour :s

Comment: a wise choise ;p you might be able to automate it, though, if you care enough - reflection that iterates the types and properties for some `partial class` file (or files) that you then drop in. Not elegant, but should only take a few minutes to script

Comment: Thank you for your help but it seems that what I am looking for is not the xxxSpecified fields. I want to be able to detect that a field was not present in xml or a way to tell the serializer not to serialize some data (instead of serializing with default value). I still do not know how to do it with DCS. It seems like a pretty basic behaviour to me.

Comment: Do you have control over the webservice wsdl?

Comment: @yorah : Of course not :) that would be way too easy ^^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behaviour you observe is normal: `*Specified` fields are generated only when using the XmlSerializer.

The DataContractSerializer never generates those Specified field. Instead. it will set the `IsRequired` property of the `DataMember` attribute to false (this is the default value of this property, so you won't even see it in the attribute).

---

**Outgoing messages**

You want to omit fields which have no value in outgoing messages.
The problem is that `DateTime` is a value type, which means that even if it is not set, it has a default value of "0001-01-01T00:00:00".

If you don't want to output it in the outgoing message, you can:

- Add the `EmitDefaultValue = false` property to the `DataMember` attribute. This will prevent the element from being written at all in the generated xml.
- Alternatively, change the type to `DateTime?` => this will output something like `<dateMaxValueField i:nil="true"/>` in your xml document.

Without modifying the proxy, there is no way to do it.

**Incoming messages**

The same logic applies: you will have no problem receiving messages which omit an element completely (as long as the corresponding property in the proxy class has `IsRequired = false`). Please note that as `DateTime` is a value type, you will always have it populated with its default value ("0001-01-01"). If you prefer to receive a `null` instance, then you need to modify your proxy and use the `DateTime?` type.

However, if you want to be able to parse a message containing:

```
<dateMaxValueField></dateMaxValueField>
```

then I'm afraid there is no way to do it with the DataContractSerializer.

---

**note**: The XmlSerializer allows for greater flexibility in those scenarios (when precise control over the XML is required, for compatibility reasons for instance).

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it seems that I did not have  the correct question :) Please see edit

Comment: I'm not sure you can do what you want to do with the DataContractSerializer, especially if you have no control whatsoever on the original wsdl.

Comment: OK I will mark your answer as accepted because I guess there is no other way around. What I would really need is to have EmitDefaultValue = false for my fields. But I have not find a way to output it automatically and I cannot modify manually everything. I will just rollback to good old XmlSerializer.